# How to export a plot to an HTML page

Tags: r

I have the dynamic plot that I want. I have a problem knowing how to export the plot to an HTML file so I can share the plot with others. I tried what I have below but it doesn't save the file.

```
# save the widget
library(htmlwidgets)
setwd("C:/Users/12083/Desktop/")
saveWidget(p, file=paste0( getwd(), "C:/Users/12083/Desktop/ggplotlyAreachart.html"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to save it to the concatenation of your working directory and a location on your c:\

```
file=paste0( getwd(), "C:/Users/12083/Desktop/ggplotlyAreachart.html")
```

you should probably pick one or the other, because you surely can't have both a relative and absolute path at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

use `auto_open=False`:

```
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename = 'filename.html', auto_open=False);
```

As of version 4.0, the `write_html()` function is available on `go.Figure` objects as well, so you can do `fig.write_html("path/to/file.html")` directly now too.

you can see the documentation here: https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/

Comment: That simply ends with it saying Error: object 'False' not found

Comment: The questions is tagged with R. Why do you provide an answer in python?